# Trouble with SQLite : SQL Query Error with keyword "any"

Tags: sql, database, sqlite

I'm using SQLite with Sqliteman software in Linux for SQL queries.

I made a table named student with 4 columns sid, sname, gpa, sizeofhs
when I run the query below I get this error message:

Query Error: near "select": syntax error Unable to execute statement

```
select sid, sname, sizeofhs
from student
where sizeofhs > any (select sizeofhs from student);
```

but when I remove the keyword "any", it executes without any error, what's the problem?

Comment: the query is about finding list of students not from the smallest high school.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`any` is standard SQL syntax, even if SQLite doesn't support it.  You can just replace this with `min()` like this:

```
select sid, sname, sizeofhs
from student
where sizeofhs > (select min(sizeofhs) from student);
```

Similarly, `all`, can be replaced with `max()`.

If you want to see documentation on what they do, SQL Server documentation explains it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175064.aspx).